# Indian e-visa application cannot be accepted because journey date must be at least 4 days after registration

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

I'm a British citizen.
I'm trying to submit my e-visa tourist application for arrival date 12th oct 2019.
The site gives me the option to select arrival date 12th oct 2019 however towards the end of the application, doesn't submit. upon re-entering the application id, gives me the following message:

> Your application cannot be accepted because journey date can only be after 4 days of registration. Please re-fill e-visa application.

I'm looking for options or solutions to expedite this. Are there any other solutions or ways to apply visa for India on an urgent basis?

Comment: This site https://www.ivisa.com/india-visa-application appears to offer expedited processing for an additional fee. According to https://www.tripsavvy.com/india-e-tourist-visa-information-1539765 the site is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any suggestion how to get the e-visa faster. I think I can explain how you got into this predicament because it happened to me: the cutoff time after you submit the application is measured in the Indian Time Zone (at the server), but the date shown when you make the application is your local time zone (in your browser). As India is significantly forward of the UK and USA, the application is too late.